# Can enabling android proguard prevent people decompile my code?

Tags: android-studio, proguard, reverse-engineering, decompiler

I have an android app, and it seems someone decomiple my code and uploaded to the play store. In my app, I have something that makes a call to my website through a php file like the following
http//www.test.com/get_service.php

Its hardcoded in the app as a string. That guy is making the same call using my get_service.php because whenever I change something in the get_service.php, it would reflected on their app.

I just noticed that apps like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.njlabs.showjava&hl=en
is able to decompile my android app.

So I tried enabling the Proguard on my app, and test it on my own phone. I haven't release the app yet, but it seems the app is still able to decompile my code. Is there a way to hide my string? so that even if someone decompile my code, he won't be able to see the get_service.php file.

```
 android {
buildTypes {
    release {
        // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
        // your project's release build type.
        minifyEnabled true

        // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
        // Android Gradle plugin.
        shrinkResources true

        // Includes the default ProGuard rules files that are packaged with
        // the Android Gradle plugin. To learn more, go to the section about
        // R8 configuration files.
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
...
```

}

Comment: Attacker would add FAKE CA certificate to the android device and make MiTM setup with generation of SSL certificates on the fly and would listen to communications between app and server to deduce API. Attacker will not need to decompile anything at all to reverse engineer API endpoints.  So I suggest you to re-think protection of your server data from absolutely different point of view.

Comment: Actually the data itself is not private. It is just that I did a lot calculations on the server, and I want to prevent others from getting the result. I want only my app to have access to it, rather than other apps calling my server.

Comment: No, the ProGuard won't stop anyone from seeing the string